# Carthage and Git : URL for git repository buried under directories

Tags: git, github, xcode7, carthage

We have Github paid repository for our company. And we have a git repo of all the **libraries**. The repo directory structure is like shown below. And those libraries (Library-1 and Library-2) project is buried under Level-n directory.

Now I need to integrate these two libraries into my project. And I am using Carthage.

***For carthage update, how can I mention the URL of the libraries in git repository?***
Github.com/MyCompany/iOS-Comp

```
iOS-Comp/
   Documents/
          Design/
          Screens/
   Tech/
          Level_1/
          Level_2/
          Level_3/
               Level_3_1/
                    Level_3_1_1/
                        Library-1/   <==== Library-1 directory
                              MyProjectTests/
                              MyProject.xcodeproj
                              MyProject/
                                    One.swift
                                    Two.swift
                                    Three.swift
                                    MyStoryboard.Storyboard
                        Library-2/   <==== Library-2 directory
                              MyProjectTests/
                              MyProject.xcodeproj
                              MyProject/
                                    One.swift
                                    Two.swift
                                    Three.swift
                                    MyStoryboard.Storyboard

               Level3_2/
               Level3_3/
               Level3_4/
   Materials/
   Assets/
   PDFs/
   Notes/
```

For `Cartfile` file How can I mention the contents?
Sample cartfile

```
# I cannot mention something like this, because my project 
# is buried under some directories.
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" >= 2.3.1

# Use a project from GitHub Enterprise
github "https://enterprise.local/ghe/desktop/git-error-translations"

# I tried to give below URL which does not work
git "https://github.com/iOS-Comp/Tech/Level_3/Level_3_1/Level_3_1_1/Library-1.git" "master"
```

Can somebody please help how can I mention Git URL in cartfile for this type of Git repo?
***For carthage update, how can I mention the URL of the git repository?***